# How to set field to @StepScoped Bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

i have a step scope bean Item Reader that i want to use in two different jobs A and B

```
@Component
@StepScope
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeItemReader implements ItemReader<String> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['date']}")
    private String date;
    @Setter
    private String folder;
```

and config class

```
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ftp")
public class BatchConfiguration {
  
  private String folderA;
  private String folderB;


    @Bean
    public Step import***StepA(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                   ItemProcessor<String, List<***>> processor,
                                   SomeItemReader reader,
                                   ItemWriter<List<***>> itemWriter,
                                   BackOffPolicy policy
    ) {
       reader.setFolderType(folderA);  <--- how to do this 
        
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("***")
                .<String, List<***>>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .backOffPolicy(policy)
                .retry(***.class)
                .retry(IOException.class)
                .retryLimit(retryLimit)
                .build();
    }

@Bean
public Step import***StepB(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                               ItemProcessor<String, List<***>> processor,
                               SomeItemReader reader,
                               ItemWriter<List<***>> itemWriter,
                               BackOffPolicy policy
) {
   reader.setFolderType(folderB);  <--- how to do this 
    
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("***")
            .<String, List<***>>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(itemWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .backOffPolicy(policy)
            .retry(***.class)
            .retry(IOException.class)
            .retryLimit(retryLimit)
            .build();
}
```

i need to set field folder but getting error that bean ItemReader is not active for current thred. I can inject it by job parameters, but want to find better way - is there any way to do it?

Comment: `I can inject it by job parameters, but want to find better way`: What's wrong with passing that as a job parameter the same way as the `date` parameter?

Comment: added to questiom some more details,  well i want to reuse this scoped bean in two different jobs and this parameter folder is constants for jobA and another constant for jobB, so i want to config it in config class , and date parameter is dynamic parameter that will be set when job start so i can set it in job launcher , instead of set constant folder every tiime

Comment: If the value is different depending on which job is launched, then it is not a constant anymore. How do you run jobs? How can we determine which job is going to be launched to know which value should be passed in to the reader? This is key to answer your question. Where are those values of `folder` coming from? Job parameters, application properties, JVM settings?

Comment: application propetries

Comment: In that case, you can inject the properties using a SpEL expression, similar to the one you used for the job parameter.

Comment: no, I can't do that, because it's not two bins, but one! I want to use it in two different jobs, because the only difference between them is the folder parameter, which is what I want to set at the configuration stage....